# c++, msxml and smart pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smart-pointers, msxml

I need parse some XML and wrote some helpers. I am not expert in C++, actually I wrote with c more then seven years ago. So, I would to make sure, is the approach, what i use correct or not :)

1) I implemented some simple helpers, to take care about exceptions.
For example:

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> create_element(CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> xml_doc, string element_name) {
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> element;

    HRESULT hr = xml_doc->createElement((BSTR)element_name.c_str(), &element);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        hr_raise("Failed to create XML element '" + element_name + "'", hr);

    return element;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> element = xmlh::create_element(xml_doc, "test");
    //..
    // save xml to file
}
```

is it ok? I mean can i return smart pointer as function result? Is this approach free from leaks?

2) Also i use some smartpointer as Class Members.
Like this:

```
class XMLCommand {
    public:
        XMLCommand(std::string str_xml);
        ~XMLCommand(void);
    protected:
        CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> xml_doc;
}


XMLCommand::XMLCommand(string str_xml) {
    xml_doc = xmlh::create_xml_doc();
}

// some methods below uses xml_doc
```

The question is the same, is it correct and free from leaks?

Thanks.

Comment: `HRESULT hr = xml_doc->createElement((BSTR)element_name.c_str(), &element);`  => `(BSTR)element_name.c_str()` looks suspicious for me.. `BSTR` is based on `WCHAR` with length prefix.. and `element_name` is `string` which normally uses `char`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work fine. When returning a smart pointer from function, the result is stored before the temporaries are destructed, so as long as you store it in a `CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement>` when you call create_element you will get the desired results (e.g., `CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> resElem = create_element(...);`. Optimized C++ will very likely even not bother with temporaries and such and just use `resElem` instead of `element` inside your `create_element()` method, speeding up the process (google Return Value Optimization for details).

The latter case is pretty much textbook smart-pointer usage. I can't think of a case that will fail. One danger when using smart pointers in general though is to be aware of and/or avoid circular dependencies, which can cause smart pointers to never delete their contained object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not think about optimization, it very simple console application which uses high loaded third party API. So simple code in client part is more important for me that its speed. in fact I had doubt about assignment result. I feared that CCompPtr<> creates an object and function result rewrites it and first object is leaked.

Comment: Fair concern - just creating a smart pointer will not create an instance of an object anymore than `Shape * pShape;` will create a `Shape` object. More importantly, when you call `CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> resElem = create_element(...);`, you aren't first creating a CComPtr<> and then initializing it using `operator=`, you are actually constructing the `CComPtr<>` using the copy constructor for that type! So even if for some insane reason the default constructor for `CComPtr<>` instantiated an object, you aren't in this case even calling the default constructor.